# grep matched string plus letters before and after

Tags: string, awk, grep

I have two files with strings where the strings in `fileA` matches part of the strings in `fileB`. Every string is unique and only has 1 match. 
I would like to match strings in `fileA` to the strings in `fileB` and print the match and 10 characters before and after of the match.

Maybe `grep -f` would work, but how do I get the 10 characters before and after.

FileA

```
     TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTT
     ACTGTACAGGCCACTGCCTTGC
     TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTT
```

FileB

```
     CCAGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTTTGAGGGTCTATGATACCACCCGGTACAGGAGA
     TAACTGTACAGGCCACTGCCTTGCCAGG

     CTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTGGTCGGGTTGTGACATTGCCCGCTGTGGAGATA
     ACTGCGCAAGCTACTGCCTTGCTAG

     GCTTGGGACACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATATGAACCTGCTAAGCTATGGAATGTAAAG
     AAGTATGTATTTCAGGC

     CTGTAGCAGCACATCATGGTTTACATACTACAGTCAAGATGCGAATCATTATTTGCTGCT
     CTAG
```

Comment: `grep` can only show `n` preceding or following lines, AFAIK. Your problem is also hard because 10 characters may be on one or two lines, as well as the match itself, am I correct?

Comment: Is it possible to make it one line instead of two? The two lines are together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop over fileA and grep:

```
while read line ; do
    grep -o  ".\{0,10\}$line.\{0,10\}" fileB.txt
done < fileA.txt
```

This example assumes that the contents of fileA.txt will not contain special characters which could break the regex. Otherwise you need to escape them:

```
while read line ; do
    search=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\\0/g' <<< "$line")
    grep -o  ".\{0,10\}$search.\{0,10\}" fileB.txt
done < fileA.txt
```

Comment: +1 for `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\\0/g'` I  find it totally awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to pre-process a pattern and send it through stdin:

```
sed 's/^/.{,10}/;s/$/.{,10}/' fileA | grep -oEf - fileB
```

Here, the sed part produces something like this:

```
.{,10}TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTT.{,10}
.{,10}ACTGTACAGGCCACTGCCTTGC.{,10}
.{,10}TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTT.{,10}
```

and we use the `-E` option for extended regexes. The `-` after `-Ef` says we want to use the standard input as the file argument (to `-f`).

Comment: I also thought about this first. Why not? :) I would like to see some benchmarks depending on the size of both files. However, the escaping part (check my answer) might also need to be done here, having real world data.

Comment: How to output only the match not the whole line from fileB?